# C++ calculator doesn't work for * operator

Tags: c++, debugging

I am learning c++ using Stroustrup's Programming Principles and Practice and there is this example code that one is to debug and make it work. I have made the corrections and when you enter an arithmetic expression that uses the + or - operator, it works. However when I enter an expression with the * operator, nothing happens. I have used debuggers to help me walk through the code but I've not been able to figure it out. The book uses a non standard include file [std_lib_facilities.h](http://ideone.com/9zq9KF)

The actual calculator program is [here](http://ideone.com/QBeb2g). Can someone be kind enough to help me figure out why an expression like 2*3; produce no result while 2+3; works?

PS: as per the program a valid expression must have `;` at the end to trigger a print. So 2+3; is correct and will trigger and print but 2+3 without a `;` will just cause the cursor to just keep blinking. Please also not that, its the first attempt at producing a calculator program so it is missing a lot of features. My concern at the moment is to work out why a simple arithmetic expression involving the `*` operator does not work. Thanks.

**[EDIT]**

Thanks @KonradRudolph for your answer. One thing that stumped me though was, when I used the gdb debugger (I'm on linux), the debugger will not step into term when I enter an expression with a *. Now I know there was an error but, I was expecting it to at least step into the function and hang somewhere in there. Why won't the debugger step into a function that has an error? That will be more helpful.

Comment: There is a comment at the top of the file that says it contains deliberate logic errors. Have you found them all?

Comment: The comment also says "If that gets tedious, compare the code to that in the book (or posted source code)". How does your code compare to the version in the book?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you simply didn’t make all necessary corrections.

In `term`:

```
    switch (t.kind) {
    case '*':
        left *= primary();
        t = ts.get();
    case '/':
        {    
            double d = primary();
            if (d == 0) error("divide by zero");
            left /= d; 
            t = ts.get();
            break;
        }
    default: 
        ts.putback(t);     // put t back into the token stream
        return left;
    }
```

`case '*'` is missing a `break` statement.

There may be more errors.

Comment: (I also have some issues with the code in general, and the `std_lib_facilities.h` in particular – what was Stroustrup thinking?!)

Comment: Maybe he was thinking that it was more important for learners to actually practice coding, rather than writing dozens of `#include` before they can do anything.  (The book is to teach _programming_, not the quirks of the standard libaray.)

Comment: @James I don’t oppose the *existence* of the header but (some of) its *content*. Have you looked at it?

Comment: I also have some issues with C++. What was Stroustrup thinking?!